# replace some values in a col of data frame by using condition from an other col which is in second data frame

Tags: r

I want to replace some values in a col of the data frame by using condition from the other col which is in the second data frame:

df1

```
Id Dad Mom
2  3  9
5  6  12
9  6  10
11 3  16
```

df2

```
Id Dad Mom
4  3  9
9  6  12
2  6  10
20 3  16
```

I want to replace `Dad = 0` in df1 if `Id` in df1 = `Id` in df2

both df length is not equal.

Comment: `df1 <- Id Dad Mom ...` is not a valid R command. Please provide a reproducible form next time.

Comment: please share expected output, it's not clear what you want

Answer (score 1):

df1 Dad replaced with 0.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Id Dad Mom
2  3  9
                  5  6  12
                  9  6  10
                  11 3  16", header  = T)


df2 <- read.table(text = "Id Dad Mom
                  4  3  9
                  9  6  12
                  2  6  10
                  20 3  16", header = T)


df1$Dad[df1$Id %in% df2$Id] <- 0

df1

> df1
  Id Dad Mom
1  2   0   9
2  5   6  12
3  9   0  10
4 11   3  16
>
```